# Solutions and projects will not display

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I was using C# in Visual Studio 2008 when all of a sudden the solutions and project vanished from the properties box. The node where you get a break down of your solutions and projects has gone. It maybe a setting I need to change but why did this happen?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2008 Open your solution.
Click View -> Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the Solution Explorer.

Check that it isnt minimised on the right, or see if you can make it appear again (I'm guessing in the View menu)

Comment: The solution Exexplorer just was not there at all. I have it back not though. Thank you